# Get selectd list value in foundation dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation drop-down

You can have a look at it here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#

I've created a dropdown with the following code

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" >Date Range  </a>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown large date-menu" drop-down-content>
        <li id="custom">Custom</li>
        <li id="today">Today</li>
        <li id="yesterday">Yesterday</li>
        <li id="sundaytoToday">This Week(Sun-Today)</li>
        <li id="montoToday">This Week(Mon-Today)</li>
     </ul>
```

I want to get the value/id of the selected element

I've tried like below, but it's not working

```
$('#drop1').click(function(){
  var ss=$('#drop1').val();
  console.log(ss);  
});
```

I'm a newbie to programming any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** How to close the dropdown on click?

Comment: i'hv updated code please check, to hide dropdown

Answer (score 2):

You need [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) not [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val).

`.val()` works with form elements like `input, select, radio, checkbox` etc.

```
$('#drop1 li').click(function(){
  var ss = $(this).text(); //this refers to current element clicked here.
  //to get id
  var id = this.id;
  console.log(ss, id);  
});
```

[“this” Keyword](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Answer (score 2):

here is correction

```
    $('#drop1 li').click(function(){
      var id=$(this).attr('id');//to get id of clicked element
      console.log(id);  
var h=$(this).text();//to get text of clicked element
      console.log(h);  
    });
```

**update**

```
    $('#drop1 li').click(function(){
          var id=$(this).attr('id');//to get id of clicked element
          console.log(id);  
    var h=$(this).text();//to get text of clicked element
          console.log(h);  
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
$('.open').removeClass('open');
        });
```

Comment: the selector should be just `'#drop1 li'`.. and `var id = this.id` will do

Comment: in question he didn't specified that he want id of li or ul

Comment: Is there any alternative for fade out, when it fadeout when i reclick on this it is not showing dropdown i need to click couple of times to get the dropdown back

Comment: code is updated $('.open').removeClass('open'); added

Answer (score 1):

as per [doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#), class `open` is added to selected element. you can get selected using:

```
 $('#drop1').click(function(){
   var ss=$('this).find('.open').html();
   console.log(ss);  
 });
```